# Device not receive message from GCM

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use GCM to send notification from server to our device.

Everything follow this guide: 
http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

After create an application, a server key, and my app receive a token from GCM, i send message to GCM using those key, token.

Here is what GCM reply to my request:

```
{"multicast_id":8176461798984692114,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1420006852349947%174fccaaf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

This Json indicate that message already sent successful. But our device didn't receive anything.

We did this for few time, even changing server key to browser key, change project, or use example from google site instead of above guide example, but nothing work. So i want to know what the possible problem for device not receiving message.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Did you tested in debug mode?

Comment: sorry about that and thank for edited my post. now i hope to receive an answer fast if possible since it quite urgent on my site :(

Comment: @Yasir Ali : i added log into almost every class but didn't see any log write out.

Comment: try to run your android application in debug mode, and add debug points on GcmMessageHandler-> onHandleIntent() to see wether you receive debug control or not, because if you are using android studio, it sometimes don't show Log. 

Also try to follow this tutorial... http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html

Comment: @Yasir Ali : My server doesn't have any web interface so i still have to use example from previous guide for server side. I will with device side then. Also im not using studio but eclipse. Since i work with other kind of project too, not only android.

Comment: Cross check your android code, with the tutorial I sent to you (not the server code). and then debug your android code, let me know.

Comment: @Yasir Ali : Sorry for this late reply since it quite bothersome to run in debug mode with our computer. But thank you. I use the code in your link and it working fine for me. It both log the content to catlog and create a notification for my device. Something must be wrong with how other app receive this message. Could you create an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question that your notification has been sent, so then the issue is on android code, you have to cross check your android code. Look at this tutorial...

http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html

And cross check your android code with this one, and then debug your android code.